# NS2 sudo apt-get install xgraph

Tags: ns2, ns-3

Please come across this problem to install xgraph in linux mint 19.1

```
nassim@nassim-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install xgraph
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet xgraph
```

English translation of output messages (note that this might not correspond exactly to strings which are produced when language is set to English):

```
Reading packet lists.. Done
Constructing dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Error: Cannot find the package xgraph
```

What is the solution, please

Comment: The following might still be relevant, although the context there was an old version of ubuntu. https://askubuntu.com/questions/492516/e-package-xgraph-has-no-installation-candidate

Comment: The Ubuntu 16.04 package `xgraph` is the best choice for later Ubuntu / Mint versions https://drive.google.com/file/d/1idXGOZ0W5PmOlKM8p6_qlIRY6U5dJ1Q4/view?usp=sharing → Please install the package with `gdebi`.

Comment: @KnudLarsen It worked, thanks